# Where do I obtain R squared for the power analysis of multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, statistical-power

I have a regression dataset and want to check if the amount of samples is sufficient. For this I conduct a power analysis.

For the power analysis of a multiple regression model, I need to obtain the effect size $f$, for which I need the variance explained $R^2$.

Do I specify a $R^2$ as a parameter or do I compute it from a dataset I have?